# Unwanted links in HTML document

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I need help about removing unwanted links in my HTML document. The problem is that every element in my document that is located after navbar is linked to the page which is last linked IN my navbar, for example, if last element in my navbar is linked to "contact.html", all other elements in the document are linked to the same page, although they are in completely different divs, and although they don't have link at all. Can someone help me remove those unwanted links?

```
<div>
    <h3 href="index.html"> Početna</h3>
    <h3 href="onama.html"> O Nama</h3>
    <h3 href="razvojniput.html"> Razvojni Put</h3>
    <h3 href="kolekcija.html"> Kolekcija</h3>
    <h3 href="prodajnamesta.html"> Prodajna Mesta</h3>
    <h3 href="kontakt.html"> Kontakt</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: please share your source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't post the code, I can't say for sure. It seems like you are missing the `</a>` tag after each link, or just after the last link.

Edit: Based on the code you shared I would recommend using `<a>` tags for the links, inside or replacing the `<h3>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an `<h3>` a hyperlink you need to nest the link tag `<a>` within the `<h3>`:

```
<h3><a href="index.html">Početna</a></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

href is only valid on `<a>` and `<area>` elements. Your browser is unsure what you mean when you do things that are invalid, and is trying to do something but there's no guarantee it will work.

Change those `<h3>` elements to `<a>`.

Also, HTML5 is intended to be semantic - by putting all those "links" in as `<h3>` you're telling the browser you have a bunch of headings (and, technically, no links). Again, it may look okay to you in your browser, but for people using a screen-reader this will be annoying and confusing.

Finally,  if this is your site navigation,  replace the `<div>` with `<nav>`. This informs browsers and screen readers that this is navigation and not just some more content.